# An archive file is broken when it was copied immediately after generated

Tags: rust, gzip, tar

I'm new for Rust and learning it everyday.
I wrote a code to create a zipped tarball and just copy itself. I referred below.
https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/compression/tar.html#compress-a-directory-into-tarball.
An archive file is generated properly but the copied one was broken. Unable to extract. I'm not sure about the reason.
Do you have any idea?

Cargo.toml

```ini
[dependencies]
tar = "0.4.38"
flate2 = "1.0.25"
```

main.rs

```rust
use flate2::{write::GzEncoder, Compression};
use std::fs::{self, File};

fn main() {
    let tar_gz = File::create("archive.tar.gz").unwrap();
    let enc = GzEncoder::new(tar_gz, Compression::default());
    let mut tar = tar::Builder::new(enc);
    // a directory including some files and directories
    tar.append_dir_all("target_dir", "target_dir").unwrap();
    tar.finish().unwrap();
    fs::copy("archive.tar.gz", "archive2.tar.gz").unwrap();
    // archive2.tar.gz is copied but broken
}
```

Comment: Is there a `close()` syscall before the copy starts? (You might use `strace` to check). If you can confirm that, you'll know where to focus (`tar.finish()` seems fine, but is there an equivalent you're missing for `enc`?) -- ...indeed, reading the GzEncoder docs, there's a `finish` call for the `GzEncoder` too, and you also want the file itself to be closed and flushed.

Comment: You should `drop(tar_gz);` before the `fs::copy` (and clear any possible borrowing errors resulting from that) to make sure that the tar/gz/file-layers have flushed all of their data to disk. As it is now, you are probably copying the file in a truncated state.

Comment: Try adding `drop(tar);` before `fs::copy(...)`, or wraping everything except the last line in a extra set of `{}`

Answer (score 4):

You need to call [`enc.flush()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush) before copying. This ensures that data remaining in the buffer of `GzEncoder` is written to the file.

Since `enc` is already owned by the tar writer, you can use [`into_inner`](https://docs.rs/tar/latest/tar/struct.Builder.html#method.into_inner) to convert back to `GzEncoder` and call `tar.into_inner().flush()`.

Comment: Thanks! I could resolve by `tar.into_inner().unwrap().finish().unwrap();`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, it's resolved. Thanks!

```rust
tar.finish().unwrap();
drop(tar); // <-- added
fs::copy("archive.tar.gz", "archive2.tar.gz").unwrap();
```